# Cannot View Active Directory within Azure

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id

I have an Azure subscription - created and owned by me. I'm the service administrator.

I have set up a colleague as a co-administrator so they could sort out Active Directory for me.

My colleague has set up AD - syncing every nn mins as I understand it.

When he goes into manage.windowsazure.com --> Active Directory he sees both the "Default Directory" (which I can see) and our "MyCompany Domain".

I can only see the "Default Directory". Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4):

You can only see the directories you're a member of. Ask your colleague to add you to the "MyCompany Domain" directory.